# Are there any airports which use a metro to transport cargo?

Tags: airport, cargo, transport-category

Many airports around the world are increasingly being joined by Metro conveniencing people. Majorly, it is people who probably will use the metro. I do have a sneaking suspicion that the metro would also be a pretty inexpensive good carrier. Two things which I think work in its favor -

a. Security on Airport Metros is higher so that much less hassle. 
b. Most of these Metros run on specific times so it's easier as it's consistent.

Are there any airports that people know that transport air cargo via metros after being bought by Aircraft ?

Comment: How do you define metro? Do you simply mean an underground train?

Comment: Interesting question.  A metro could carry only a small amount of cargo, though.  Why not just install a spur line to allow a rail carrier access to the airport?  Economies of scale snd all...

Comment: metro, for e.g. https://www.mmrcl.com/map/ click Airports and you'll see what I mean. This is few years away, and Delhi Metro Express Line http://www.delhimetrorail.com/Airport-Express-Line.aspx which is already operational.

Comment: @acpilot - could you share what you mean by spur line ? Could you elaborate a bit please. I haven't heard that term before.

Comment: A spur line is an offshoot of an existing main line.

Comment: [Metros](http://cargofacts.com/ameriflight-n807m/) are commonly used to transport cargo *between* airports.

Comment: @JonathanWalters I think we differ on what we mean by Metros :(

Comment: @shirish Sorry, it was a joke ;)

Comment: ah...ok, didn't get it :(

Answer (score 4):

DFW Airport's original train system had cars built to carry mail and luggage.  Most of the system was never used because it was slow, and there were worries that it was hard to train employees to interface with it. I would guess that a lot of airports have not tried such as system because their trans are optimized for passengers, so it is faster to just move luggage across the tarmac on trucks.

Edit: Jonathan Walters mentioned that Denver also had a system, but it was buggy so they stopped using it.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Do you have any sources about this?

Comment: Best I can get you is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vought_Airtrans) Wikipedia article. The citations seems to be old, so I cannot completely verify them, but there are a few photos of the system, so I tend to believe it. As for the last part, about the system, I simply am making an educated guess.

Comment: You can add Denver International. Designed to use baggage carts on rails, but had many problems, never fully implemented, decommissioned in 2005

Comment: It's still not clear from the question but I think it's asking about a train to and from the airport, not within the airport.

Answer (score 1):

Few months back, I visited India and landed at their [Indira Gandhi International Airport](http://www.newdelhiairport.in/). During my exit, I was about to take the cab to my hotel but then I found their [Airport Express Line](http://www.delhimetrorail.com/AirportExpressLine.aspx). So they had this metro service for their passengers and it connects to major parts of New Delhi.

Later during my stay there, I found out that Airport metro had a bit higher fare than their local metro. But the services and the kind of security they provide was great. Passengers before boarding Airport metro can give their luggage at the time of boarding the train and then no need take tension at the airport. I do not know if they transport air cargo or not but if they are transporting passengers luggage they might transport air cargo.

Here I found a [link](http://www.delhimetrorail.com/press_reldetails.aspx?id=7GS2nclwuyBuclld) which explains that they will start cargo service on their Airport Express Line.